# Select2 set tokenSeparators using data attribute

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I'm trying to set `tokenSeparators` option using `data-token-separators="[',']"` but nothing happens, what is the right syntax to pass array of token separators in data attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data-token-separators="[',']"` is the correct way to do it.  You may want to update to a newer version of Select2 as I found earlier versions were not handling this feature very well.

Answer (score -1):

Recreate the select2 object with the updated settings.

So lets say your original separator was:

```
$(".js-example-tokenizer").select2({
    tags: true,
    tokenSeparators: [',', ' ']
})
```

Then it should look like:

```
$(".js-example-tokenizer").select2({
    tags: true,
    tokenSeparators: [',']
})
```

Visit [select2](https://select2.org/tagging#automatic-tokenization-into-tags) if you want more information.

Comment: I made it, but prefer data-attributes in some situations.